# synchronizing http response with socket connection

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using a http server with a socket connection , when http request hits, socket connection sends message to different client which performs a http request after this http response the client replies to the message and and response of initial http request is send.
My problem is first http request sometimes get response successfuly and sometimes not, I think there is a sync problem, how to solve it.

code for creating socket and httpserver -

```
const app = require('express')()
bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const net = require('net');
var client;
var res1,currentReq;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// http requests listener
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

app.listen(8001, () => console.log('Http server listening on port 8001'));

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// http requests handling
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

app.post('/makeCall', (req, res) => {
        console.log('sd' + req.body)
        res1 = res;
        currentReq='makeCall';
        console.log('{"route":"/api/makeCall","data":{"product_id":"'  + req.body.product_id + '","destination":"' + req.body.destination + '"}}');
        client.write('{"route":"/api/makeCall","data":{"product_id":"'  + req.body.product_id + '","destination":"' + req.body.destination + '"}}');

});

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Establishing tcp connection for incoming requests
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var server = net.createServer(function(connection) {
   console.log ('client has connected successfully!');
   client = connection;
   client.on('data',function(data){
   switch(currentReq) 
   {
       case 'makeCall' :
                    console.log('send make call response');
                    res1.end(data);
                    break;

   }

    console.log(data.toString());
            //res1.end(data);

  });

   connection.pipe(connection);
});


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// listener for tcp connections
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

server.listen(8000, function() {
   console.log('server for localhost is listening on port 8000');
   console.log('server bound address is: ' + server.address ());
});
```

code for client to which socket connects -

```
tcpClient.on('connect',function(){
    logger.info("[%s] , Connected to the server at %s:%s",__file,CONFIG.tcp_server_host,CONFIG.tcp_server_port);
    logger.info("[%s] , TCP client info %s",__file,tcpClient.address().address);
});

//  Handle data event
tcpClient.on('data',function(data){
    logger.info('[%s] , Data recevied',__file);

    // Convert the Buffer to JSON object
    var reqInfo;
    reqInfo = JSON.parse(data.toString());

    if(reqInfo!=null){

        switch(reqInfo.route){

            case '/api/makeCall':;
            var product_id      = reqInfo.data.product_id;
            var destination = reqInfo.data.destination;
            var test = {};
            var source;
            var myJSONObject = {'product_id':product_id};

             MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
              var dbo = db.db("mapping");
              dbo.collection("mapping").findOne({"id":product_id},function(err,result)
              {
                if(err)
                {
                  throw err;
              }
      JSON.stringify(result);
      sourceDB = result.source;

        // Set the options for HTTPS request
        options.method              = "POST";
        options.url                 = "url";
        options.json                = true;
        options.auth                = {
            user: '123',
            password: '123'
        };
            options.body                = {"Source": sourceDB,"Destination": destination} ;
            logger.info('[%s] , HTTPS request options : %o',__file,options);
            request(options,function(error,res1,body){
             tcpClient.write('Sending data to Falcon');

            });

        });
  });
```

Comment: One problem I see is that you're assuming that when a tcp packet arrives that it's a fully formed message that you can just go use.  That is not necessarily the case.  Your incoming tcp data can arrive in packets of any size and it might take several packets to make a full message.  You need some sort of data format on your tcp socket so you know when you have a complete message.  I don't know how much flexibility you have, but a webSocket connection does this for you.

Comment: And, you should also surround your `JSON.parse()` with a `try/catch` so if there is any problem with the incoming data, you can appropriately handle that error.  And, remove the `if (err) throw err` from your code.  That does nothing useful.  Replace it with real error handling.

Comment: i printed data before `res1.end(data)` and it is printing correctly meaning the packet is fully formed, additionally if write `tcpClient.write('Sending data to Falcon');` outside of response callback of http request (in client) http response(from server) works correctly, so I think incomplete packets is not causing the problem

Comment: You may be getting lucky with full packets arriving now, but it's not a reliable way to code.  It can fail in the future.  This is not a proper way to code.

Comment: i understand your concern but i am unable to understand why print is giving correct output but reponse is still not correctly going.

Comment: Lots more things wrong in this code.  You can't stuff res into a higher scoped variable `res1` and use it elsewhere.  Your whole design logic here is just messed up.  And what is `connection.pipe(connection);` supposed to do?